# Escaping backslash using sub

Tags: regex, r, replace

I have a string `template`, read from a file, with the content:

```
template <- "\\begin{tabular}\n[results]\n\\end{tabular}"
```

I want to replace `results` with some text I have generated in my code, to compose a laTeX table, but when I run:

```
sub("\\[results\\]","text... \\hline text...",template)
```

I have the following output:

```
"\\begin{tabular}\ntext... hline text...\n\\end{tabular}"
```

The backslash is not escaped and I don't understand why, because I'm using `\\` for this purpose.

I am using R-3.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex engine is consuming the `\\` for a potential capture group, you need to add two more backslashes:

```
sub("\\[results\\]","text... \\\\hline text...",template)
[1] "\\begin{tabular}\ntext... \\hline text...\n\\end{tabular}"
```